# Any companies out there that given a carbon frame could replicate it?

Tags: customization

I snapped my frame and I really liked the bike setup I had. Is there a company out there that will make a carbon framed based on one provided.

Comment: The company that made the original? It seems very unlikely that a company would offer the service of making counterfeit bike frames, as that could cause all kinds of legal problems.

Comment: Also a 1 to 1 'external' replica would not have the properties of the original bike. It is impossible to replicate the layering, the properties of the fibres and mats, the resins, in short all the engineering that went into the construction of the original.

Comment: Carbon frame can be repaired.

Comment: Did your bike have a brand and model?  Could be you can search ebay for that and find something as a base, then combine best of both bikes.

Comment: I took it to the shop to be repaired and they found two other issues recommending against repair. Call me paranoid but buying a second hand carbon frame, maybe that's how the marketing department gets ya.

Comment: @Rider_X: Although there are carbon frames and carbon frames. Cheapo Chinese frames are more expensive to repair than getting a new one.

Comment: Do approach the original manufacturer. They owe you nothing, but offering you a good replacement deal or something else is not unlikely - plenty of high-end manufacturers like to make old customers happy. Also there is quite often a model which is known by the manufacturer to have premature failure, and they will want to sort you out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to get out a tape measure and compare your current bike's measurements to all the geometry charts on the internet, then buy something comparable. Also, depending on the age of your bike look for a similarly-sized model from the same manufacturer. Carbon frame molds are expensive & time-consuming to build so some companies use the same mold for multiple seasons, swapping out the components. Finally - you "snapped" a carbon frame and there is no warranty support? That's pretty rare, unless you're not the original owner. At the very least most manufacturers have a crash replacement program where you get the same/newer model for ~ 50% of retail. Check it out.

Comment: Makes sense. The bike was 5 years old so not covered. I had searched before but never put manufucture for some reason, and now I see one that looks similar, time to get the tape measure out. Thanks.